# How can I load a .po file downloaded from Transifex to my Django-CMS project?

Tags: django, internationalization, gettext, django-cms

I installed Django-CMS, everything is fine and sweet.

Now I want to have the french translation of the `cmsplugin-blog` and I discover through this link (https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/cmsplugin-blog/language/fr/) that the French translation is 100% complete.  So I downloaded the .po from the Transifex web interface.

Now how can I use it ?

I tried copying the downloaded .po file to my project/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/ dir.  The file is named `for_use_cmsplugin-blog_djangopo_fr.po`.

I ran `django-admin.py compilemessages` and now I have a `.mo` file of the same name.  After restarting `runserver`, the translations don't appear.. although they do for my own `django.po/mo` file.

Must I do something special so it detects that file, or must I merge its contents inside the django.po file ?  If I do so, when I run `makemessages` the next time, won't it zap all the translations in the merged portions of the `django.po` file that it doesn't find in some files in my project ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to rename the file you downloaded to `project/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`, so that Django finds that file. For more information, refer to the [Django Localization docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) on how it discovers your files.